# BlackBerry Technical Specification

Tags: blackberry, signal-processing

I'm having trouble locating BlackBerry techical specifications and their website is a mess.  They also don't have a number that I can use to easily contact them.

This isn't exactly a coding question, but what does the BlackBerry audio API look like, and where can I get technical specifications on audio?  Specifically, I'm trying to find out more information on Audio-In, specifically, through the Mic-In on the 3.5 mm jack.

Unfortunately, before I can proceed, I need to know such things like sampling rate, data width, etc.

Direction to the right resource or if you know off of the top of your head is appreciated.

Comment: I think a request for information on APIs is programming related and belongs here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't agree more, the BlackBerry site is a maze!

You can find the API [here](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/).

I am not sure about the audio side of BlackBerry I'm afraid but check out 
the [BlackBerry support forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board?board.id=java_dev) as there are some guys who work for RIM on there.

How about [this post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&message.id=32304)?

I am sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will be sure to look at it.  seems like since they have the business market on more or less lockdown, they've decided they don't need to provide a support number for their device, even if it's a question of hardware specs.

This helps greatly however!